# Laravel 5 retrieve checkbox array value

Tags: laravel, synchronization

I am creating project with laravel 5, i did store checkbox array value into table using below's code

```
$permission_id = Input::get('permission_id');
        if(is_array($permission_id))
        {
            $permission_id = implode(',', $permission_id);

        }

        $userpermissionlist->permission_id = $permission_id ;
```

it's stored value like 2,3,4 now i need to explode this value and selected checkbox value will be checked.. how can i do that..My view code is

```
{!! Form::checkbox('permission_id[]', $userpermission->id) !!}
```

Comment: The following boolean will be true if the checkbox should be checked:
`array_search($id, explode(',', $ids)) !== false`

Comment: Sorry here which variable i can give in $ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the third parameter to true in checkbox() method will mark the checkbox as checked. Assuming you have $checked_permission_ids which is an array of all the checked ids, you could do this:

```
@foreach( $user_permissions as $userpermission )

{!! Form::checkbox('permission_id[]', $userpermission->id, in_array( $userpermission->id, $checked_permission_ids ) ) !!}

@endforeach
```

Comment: hi i tried this but it thrown Trying to get property of non-object eception